# Blender 3.5 needs a fully opaque viewport

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

[image]Blender 3.5 has a semi opaque viewport by default.  I tried reinstalling it but it was still semi opaque.  Can someone tell me how to toggle it to fully opaque?  I am a bit of a noob with Blender but I love that program.  TYIA!

Comment: Maybe a problem with your graphic card, if you have an AMD, try to switch to a previous driver?

Comment: I have a recent Nvidia card.  I am running Rocky Linux 9.  Maybe I will try and boot to Windows even though I don't want to lol

Comment: This has been asked recently: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297879/how-to-turn-the-background-solid-gray.

Comment: John Eason thank you very much my friend!  It works now.  Please post your answer and I will approve it!

Comment: That is not my answer. I simply posted a link to a previous answer which is the normal procedure here.

Comment: Okay well regardless thanks for the help :)

Comment: @JohnEason Good find, was looking for that myself but my search-fu failed me. @ Confident If the the linked post was useful [upvote the answer that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I have these questions on a RSS feed and searched for "background"! :^)